Find effective memory access time in a system with TLB as well as physical address cache
The problem statement:
I have a simple paging system with a TLB and a Physical Address Cache.
Here's the flow:

CPU generates logical address=(p,d)

Given "p", CPU seeks in its TLB cache if there's "f". Assume this time as c1.

If not present in TLB, hit page table. Assume this time for accessing memory as m.


Now you've got The frame number.
Based on frame number, you want to find the contents.

Look into physical address cache if there's a corresponding content for given frame number. The time for cache access is c2.

If not available in cache, look in the main memory itself, the time for memory access is m.


The correct solution
(c1+m-mx1)+(c2+m-mx2)
My solution
(c1+m-mx1).(c2+m-mx2)
How  I arrived here?
I caculated the net probability like this.
TLB_hit.PAC_hit+TLB_hit.PAC_miss+TLB_miss.PAC_hit+TLB_miss.PAC_miss
which led to
(TLB_hit+TLB_miss).(PAC_hit+PAC_miss)
And the rest is obvious problem solving.
Where did I miss? Can anyone explain?
